# Matrix Algebra Questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I would like you to help me with two questions I am stuck in. You can call these homework questions. It would be helpful if you can give me non-trivial hints instead of complete solution.

1) Let $A$ be a matrix such that $Rowspace(A)=Coulmnspace(A)$. Prove or disprove that A is symmetric.

2) Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two matrices such that $Columnspace(A)=Columnspace(B)$ and $BA=AB$. Prove or disprove that $A=B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample for both:

$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Well I was assuming these are true and hence trying to prove it, which of course I couldn't. But I was under the impression that if I could not, maybe someone else can prove they are true!
But in general, while A and B turn out to be pretty commonplace matrices,what would you suggest me when I encounter such "Prove or disprove" questions? Should I first check the identity, null, permutation, Kronecker and 1 matrices before trying to prove?

Comment: I started the first one by checking the statement "if $A$ has the same rows as it has columns, then $A$ is symmetric", either to . Really, for that first problem, any non-singular, non-symmetric, square matrix works just as well.

Comment: I think the smarter bet is to just start with $2 \times 2$ matrices.  For example, we could have had $$A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$$ for the first, and the same $A$ with
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$
for the second.  For any pair of matrices, a good way to start is always "what if one is the identity?"

Comment: I shall keep this in mind. Often I get bogged down by these kind of prove or disprove type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Two vectors can be composed from the same basis, but not be equal.
2. Did you mis-transcribe the question?  Equality is symmetric for matrices.  BA $=$ AB $\implies$ AB $=$ BA

Comment: Indeed the question was incorrect in part 2. I have edited and written the correct question. So sorry for this inconvenience!

Comment: Meanwhile, would you be kind enough to re-explain your hint to question 1? I really can't figure out your hint. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Looks like omnomnomnom gave you the answer.